# Kubernetes dashboard through Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I have Kubernetes Cluster with Ingress/Traefik controller

Also, I installed the dashboard using the standard config from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

I'm trying to access the Dashboard through Ingress, but I get 404 error

```
404 page not found
```

My ingress.yml file looks like this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
  name: app-ingress-system
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dashboard.domain.com
    secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
```

I've tried different - path: (like /dashboard, /proxy) same result

Comment: Can you post mode details regarding the configuration. Also have you tried with port 80?

Comment: Hi @Crou, thanks for the answer. I use config from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

Comment: the path in your ingress rule need to path: /dashboard

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because `kubernetes-dashboard-certs` doesnot have the file `tls.crt` and `tls.key` which are expected by traefik. You should get this in the traefik logs.

Next problems will be between traefik certificates and dashboard certificates. I still not understand how to fix properly this and configure traefik with the option :

```
 ssl.insecureSkipVerify: "true"
```

The last one I had, is that http endpoint doesnot accept login, then finally I declare the ingress that redirect http to https like this :

```
kubectl apply -f - << EOF
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dashboard.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
              servicePort: 443
EOF
```

Comment: to get past the certificates error when traefik tried to access the backend kubernetes-dashboard via SSL, i added `- --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true` to the **args** in my traefik deamonset configuration. [reference](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/overview/#insecureskipverify)

Answer (score 3):

you can access the kubernetes dashboard without disabling ssl verification for the entire traefik server, by creating custom server transport for the ingressroute

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: ServersTransport
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-transport
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

spec:
  serverName: kubernetes-dashboard
  insecureSkipVerify: true

---              
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  entryPoints:                      # [1]
    - websecure
  routes:                           # [2]
  - kind: Rule
    match:   Host(`k3sdashboard.example.xyz`) # [3]
    priority: 10                    # [4]
    services:                       # [8]
    - kind: Service 
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
      port: 443                      # [9]
      serversTransport: kubernetes-dashboard-transport
  tls:                              # [11]
    certResolver: dns-cloudflare
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works on microk8s.
In some systems must change service kubernetes-dasboard type to NodePort

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit svc kubernetes-dashboard
```

Create a tls secret for yourdomain.com must be in the same namespace  where is kubernates-dashboard, must have the crt and key files.

```
kubectl -n kube-system create secret tls yourdomain.com-tls --key="yourdomain.com.key" --cert="yourdomain.com.crt"
```

Use this code for create the ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
    #this redirect to https if try to enter over http
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    #this is required, because dashboard only run over HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    #this requiered if want to protect site
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: <here your public ip>,<here server ip if want access from server>
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - dashboard.yourdomain.com
      secretName: yourdomain.com-tls
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.yourdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 8443
```